# Django pass self to models.SET on_delete

Tags: django, django-models, django-signals

I want to modify a foreign key value when its deleted from the database. So I looked upon the doc and used on_delete=models.SET(foo) method. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.SET

This is my model definition

```
class OrderLine(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.SET(getDuplicateProduct), null=True)
    quantity = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=1)
    finalPricePerUnit = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    dateCreated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
```

And this is my method which is called on delete

```
def getDuplicateProduct(orderline):
    productToDelete = orderline.product
    # some logic to generate duplicate copy and returning it
```

However the problem here is that I can't pass argument to this method which is why I cannot know which product was deleted. I also tried using signals as specified in this answer [django model on_delete pass self to models.SET()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34918828/django-model-on-delete-pass-self-to-models-set)

I also tried using signals, but that also didn't work. I can't seem to find out a proper solution for this. 
Let me know if someone has an idea on how to achieve this.

EDIT

This is the code I am using in signals

```
@receiver(pre_delete, sender=Product)
def getDuplicateProduct(sender, **kwargs):
    product = kwargs['instance']
    orderlines = product.orderline_set.all()
    #further processing
```

Now the problem is that django tries to delete my orderlines as well (as default on_delete is set to cascade). And if I set the on_Delete to SET_NULL, it sets the foreign key to null.

EDIT -2
Here is the code I am using

```
@receiver(pre_delete, sender=Product)
def getDuplicateProduct(sender, **kwargs):
    product = kwargs['instance']
    orderlines = product.orderline_set.all()
    product.name = product.name + ' ' + product.get_type_display()
    newProduct = deepcopy(product)
    newProduct.name = product.name + ' ' + product.get_type_display()
    newProduct.pk=None
    newProduct.id=None
    newProduct.save()
    product.duplicateProductId = newProduct.id
    product.old_orderlines = orderlines
    product.save()


@receiver(post_delete, sender=Product)
def handlePostDelete(sender, **kwargs):
    product = kwargs['instance']
    newProduct = Product.objects.get(id=product.duplicateProductId)
    for orderline in product.old_orderlines:
        orderline.product = newProduct
        orderline.save()
```

EDIT-3
Posting full implementation for completeness.

```
@receiver(pre_delete, sender=Product)
def handlePreDelete(sender, **kwargs):
    product = kwargs['instance']
    orderlines = product.orderline_set.all()
    shouldCreate=False
    for orderline in orderlines:
        if orderline.order.status>1:
            shouldCreate=True
    product.shouldCreate = shouldCreate
    if shouldCreate:
        product.old_orderlines = orderlines
        product.save()
    else:
        product.save()
        return None


@receiver(post_delete, sender=Product)
def handlePostDelete(sender, **kwargs):
    product = kwargs['instance']
    shouldCreate = product.shouldCreate
    if shouldCreate:
        newProduct = deepcopy(product)
        newProduct.name = product.name + ' ' + product.get_type_display()
        newProduct.pk=None
        newProduct.id=None
        newProduct.save()
        # Do whatever you want with product.old_orderlines
        for orderline in product.old_orderlines:
            orderline.product = newProduct
            orderline.save()
```

Comment: "I will not have any reference of orderline in receiver method.". Why not? Can you post the code that you used with signals?

Comment: In your second edit, I think it is the `deepcopy` that is causing the problem. See if you can move that into the `post_delete` handler. Also you need to copy the queryset to avoid it being clobbered (I've edited my answer below).

Comment: @solarissmoke I tried moving deep copy to post_delete handler and it seems to work, thanks and sorry for late reply, went out of town for 10 days.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Signals are the right way to do this.

You can get the `OrderLine` from the signal receiver:

```
@receiver(pre_delete, sender=Product)
def getDuplicateProduct(sender, **kwargs):
    product = kwargs['instance']
    orderlines = product.orderline_set.all()
    # orderlines contains all the OrderLines foreign keyed to the product.
```

`orderlines` is a queryset which you can iterate over or [update in bulk](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1dev/ref/models/querysets/#update).

**EDIT**

Turns out the approach suggested above will not work, because by the time the `pre_delete` signal has fired Django has already determined which related models it needs to process with `on_delete`, and will overwrite these changes.

This approach will work, though it is a bit clunky:

First, in a `pre_delete` receiver:
    from copy import copy

```
@receiver(pre_delete, sender=Product)
def handlePreDelete(sender, **kwargs):
    product = kwargs['instance']
    # Store the OrderLines as a property of the object
    # Have to copy it otherwise it will be empty later
    product.old_orderlines = copy(product.orderline_set.all())
```

Then, in a `post_delete` receiver:

```
@receiver(post_delete, sender=Product)
def handlePostDelete(sender, **kwargs):
    product = kwargs['instance']
    # Do whatever you want with product.old_orderlines
    for line in product.old_orderlines:
        # ...
```

In between these two events, Django will have performed `SET_NULL` (or whatever you configured) on the OrderLines.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that django tries to delete my orderlines as well as default on_delete is set to cascade. And if I set the on_Delete to SET_NULL, it sets the foreign key to null

Comment: I thought the idea was to change the ForeignKey to point to another product before the deletion happens?

Comment: That is true, I want to point the orderlines to a new product. However I am not sure if this change is properly committed or there is a race condition.

Comment: Hmm, you are right. Django has already determine what needs to be deleted/set to null by the time this signal is fired, so this approach will not work. Let me edit the answer with an alternative approach.

Comment: I've edited the answer with an approach that should work.

Comment: What is product.old_orderlines? Are you suggesting to create one more property in product with the name old_orderlines? And as this will be a list, how will it be stored as django doesn't support one to many relationships

Comment: It is not a model field - simply a property of the python object. You can put anything in a python object. So you are putting a `queryset` into an property (that is not a model field) and then accessing it a little later. Try it.

Comment: ok, that is something new to me, thanks. Can you provide any doc for the same, meanwhile I will try your solution.

Comment: I tried this solution, but the old_orderlines is not found in the post_delete. I am getting the following error AttributeError: 'Product' object has no attribute 'old_orderlines'

Comment: I have just tested this approach and it works fine for me. Perhaps you can post the code that you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Giving support to the @solarissmoke answer, which I consider the right solution, but to give you more option I will post this. If you have the `product` instance you can have its `orderlines`. For example if you add a `related_name` to the `OrderLine.product` like so:

```
class OrderLine(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name='orderlines')
```

you can then in your signal do this:

```
@receiver(pre_delete, sender=Product)
def getDuplicateProduct(sender, **kwargs):
    product = kwargs['instance']
    orderlines = product.orderlines.all()
```

Just another way of doing that, to get the `orderlines`.