# How to access request parameters from SET value of on_delete in django model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have about 10 models each of which use User as a Foreign Key.  When the user is deleted, I want to set the values in each of these tables to the one who deletes the user. The users are being deleted through django admin area by authorized staff.

So, I guess I have to call a function and use SET of on_delete method to set the value.
This is the code as per documentation.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

def get_sentinel_user():
    return User.objects.get_or_create(username='deleted')[0]

class MyModel(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET(get_sentinel_user))
```

In my case, I want to get the user who deletes the user.  That can be obtained only from Request parameters.  How can I access request parameters in get_sentinel_user function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since a staff member is deleting other users and effectively taking ownership of the objects that belongs to the deleted user the only effective solution is to override the [delete_model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.delete_model) method in [Admin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/).

```
def delete_model(self, request, obj) :
    '''
    deletes a single item.  changes ownership
    '''
    MyModel.objects.filter(user_id=obj.pk).update(user_id=request.user.id)

    obj.delete()
```

Notice that the get_sentinel_user is no longer required because delete_model already has access to request.user

Howveer you are not out of the woods yet. The admin has a bulk delete action. You actually have to [disable the bulk delete action](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/actions/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_actions) for the user admin and replace it with one of your own for you to be in full control.

> The “delete selected objects” action uses QuerySet.delete() for
>   efficiency reasons, which has an important caveat: your model’s
>   delete() method will not be called.

Please note that bulk delete does not fire any signals for each object that's deleted so the only other django based solution that works here is to override the delete method on the User manager. However the user manager will not have access to the request.user instance ether.

Comment: But, how do I access 'request' parameters in get_sentinel_user?  The instance only has the id of the user being deleted.  I want to get the id of the user who deletes the user and that information is only in request parameter.

Comment: I'm using django.contrib.auth.models.User for users.  When the admin deletes a user, a DELETE request is triggered.  The request contains the user's information in request.user.  If it's in viewset, I can get the information from self.request.  The problem is accessing it from a model.  How do I do it?

Comment: I see we have the wrong approach all together, but also permit me to point out that the get_sentinel_user() you provided is a red herring it does not accept a request parameter.

Comment: I can get the user who deletes(i.e. superadmin) in delete() function while deleting the user.  Is it possible to send the superadmin from there so that I can catch it in post_delete?

Comment: single item deletes will fire a post_delete signal. The only trouble is with the bulk delete method in the admin. That does not fire any.

Comment: Can I send a signal with arguments in delete() function (of delete user) and receive it in the the other 10 models?

Comment: by using signals you are just adding complexity. Just add a line similar to the one I have shown above for each of the models in question. That's all

Comment: This is good.  But, as I said, I need to do call this function for each of the models that uses User as a ForeignKey?  Is it possible to get all models that uses User as a ForeignKey using some method?  That way, I can avoid hardcoding the name of the model in delete_model function.

Comment: That's a separate question and if you post it i would  be most than happy to answer.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, `on_delete.SET` designed that so it will call callable without any parameters, check it's [source code](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/_modules/django/db/models/deletion/#SET).

The actual solution to your problem can be achieved in many different ways, but good one I think is when you add column `deleted_by` to your user and make it as `ForeignKey` to user which deleted this entry. Then instead of actual deletion you add column named `is_active` and set it to False when someone deletes that user.

You can change delete behavior to update by reading [this article](https://blog.esharesinc.com/supercharging-django-productivity-at-eshares-8dbf9042825e#.711zt81xm) for example. It contains nice examples and github gists links.

And then what you really need is to pass `self` to `SET` method which can be done by using `signals`. Couple question on StackOverflow: [one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34918828/3606603), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36571834/3606603).

Comment: I cannot add deleted_by in User model because I'm using Django's User model and I don't want to add any field to it.  Using signals sounds like a good option.  But, the problem is I want to get the user_id of the user who deletes the user and not the user_id of the user being deleted.  I can get that information only from request parameters.  How do I access request parameters?

Comment: You don't have to change built in user model. Check docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model
With my approach you will have id of user who deletes and can access to it whenever you want.